# why the export keyword not working in the second scenario?

Tags: shell-script

Consider the following commands:

```
export set value=7
echo $value
export set value=70|echo $value
```

Now the output that we get:

7

7

However, shouldn't that be 70 in the second case.

somebody would pls explain what I am missing.

Comment: What is `set` for? Is it a documented keyword to `export` you found somewhere, or ... ?

Comment: set is a unix command to set or unset any variable

Comment: in this context `set` is potentially the name of a variable to export.  but probably just a programmer error that has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every command in a pipeline is executed in its own shell, so you are running `export set value=70` in a subshell which cannot modify the parent, so `echo $value` doesn't see the attempt to change the value.

Also, for POSIX shells `set` is not needed to assign to a variable, you can just do `export value=70`

Comment: value=70
echo $value -> gives the output as 70
However,
set value=70
and then 
echo $value -> gives the output as blank,

why such a behavior with set?...help is appreciated, m new to linux
any reason for particularly using set?

Comment: what does set actually does? and when should it be used?

Comment: @FarhanPatel `set` is really for modifying options and positional parameters, not "regular" variables.  For regular variables you should just do the assignment directly.  In general, `set` modifies the behavior of the shell, like `set -x` enables tracing and `set +x` turns it off.  It's not really for variables you want to use within a script or environment.  For more see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Comment: thnx... @eric renouf